# gcloud windows instance inaccessible

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam

I have a Windows Server 2012 instance running on Gcloud Compute Engine.  Just yesterday I was installing an antivirus and the program installation stopped.

I aborted the installation and rebooted the instance, but I was unable to access again to the instance.  I can't figure out any way to access this instance any more.

It doesn't appear there is a console. Is there a way to force Windows into safe mode during boot time from gcloud?  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: What antivirus program did you install?

Comment: A few points. The network is just about your only access to the VM. If you run any software on the VM that messes with the network, especially antivirus programs that may change the firewall rules, you run the risk of locking yourself out. You might have a chance of accessing the serial console and uninstalling the program, but it could be challenging. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console for info on the serial console.

Comment: I was installing ESET.  I'll take a look at the serial console and see what I can do with that, thanks!

Comment: Looks like I can't even create a command prompt channel thought the serial console.  I think it's hosed.  I'll just have to rebuild  :(
I'll be sure to take more snapshots in the future :)